# Equation for force of attraction between plates of a capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance

I was given the question:

> A parallel plate air capacitor has capacity $\mathrm{C}$, the distance of separation between plates is $\mathrm{d}$ and a potential difference $\mathrm{V}$is applied between the plates. The force of attraction between the plates of the parallel plate air capacitor is?

The given answer is $\frac { \mathrm {CV^{2}}}{ \mathrm {2d^2}}$

However, the answer I get is $\frac { \mathrm {CV^{2}}}{ \mathrm {d}}$.

**Logic for my answer:**

I know that $V = Ed$, $Q$ (the charge on the capacitor plate) $= CV$ and $C = \frac {\epsilon_o A}{d}$ (in a medium where dielectric constant = 1) and $\space F = QE$

1. $\space Q = CV$ and multiplying $C$ and $V$ from the above equation I get $ Q = \epsilon_o AE$
2. $\space F = QE\space $  hence $F = \epsilon_o AE^2$
3. Multiply and divide by $d$ to get $F = \frac {\epsilon_o A\space E^2d}{d}$
4. Substitute $C = \frac {\epsilon_o A}{d}$ and $\frac {V}{d} = E$ resulting in $F = \frac {CV^2}{d}$ as my final answer.

I'd deeply appreciate it if someone could point out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: The way you have written it, $V = E\, d$ is the potential due to *both* disks of the capacitor. When considering the force on just one of the disks, however, you must take *half* of that potential, since each disk as a whole does not "feel" its own electric field. In short, with your method, you must use $V = E\,d/2$.

This is why, instead of simply combining formulas together, it is a better idea to solve the problem more systematically, keeping in mind the underlying physics:

Assuming the two parallel plates of the capacitor are infinitely big and carry a charge density of magnitude $\sigma$ each, the electric field $\mathbf{E}$ due to *one* of the plates at a distance $d$ from its surface is given by
$$ \mathbf{E} = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}\, \mathbf{\hat{n}},$$ where $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the normal to the surface. This field is associated with a potential $$V = E\, d = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}d$$ at distance $d$. A small charge $dq = \sigma \, dA$ on the second capacitor will experience a force $$\mathbf{dF} = dq\, \mathbf{E} = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0} \, dA$$ in magnitude. Integrating over the whole area $A$ of the second capacitor, you get $$F = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0} A = \frac{C\, V^2}{2 d^2}, $$ after using your expression for the capacitance $C$.

Comment: Thank you. But what is wrong in my way of solving it?

Comment: I've just edited my answer :)

Comment: Thank you @Yejus . But I want to find the net force, so wouldn't $V=Ed$ be more appropriate?

Comment: Could you please show the simplification in the last step? I still get it as $CV^{2}/2d$ and not $d^2$

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a glitch in what you call E.
If you write the equation V = Ed, E stands for the electric field between the two plates.
If you write F = QE, E stands for the electric field produced by one of the plates. And you must understand that these are different.
Let's call the electric field produced by one of the plates E. The electric field by the other plate would be of the same magnitude but in the opposite direction. So the net field would be 2E directed towards the negatively charged plate.
The final equations are: 
Q=CV 
F = QE
V = 2Ed
You can solve it hereafter.

Comment: May I know why my answer has been downvoted?

Comment: I have not downvoted it, but I'm not sure why it is wrong..However even if $V = 2Ed$ the answer comes out wrong.

Comment: I get the same answer you've quoted in your question, though.